# Link a JAR that contains .class and .java files in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have some JAR files built with Netbeans that include the source .java file for each .class file in the hierarchy.  I get the error "Multiple dex files define SomeClass", so it looks like its trying to compile the .java files inside the JAR.  Is there a way to prevent this?

The purpose is to be able to debug the JAR file in Android Studio with proper sources attached.  I'm open to suggestions for another way to accomplish that.

Currently my Gradle build file links with

```
compile files('library.jar')
```

I am using Android Studio 0.9.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've dropped the whole combined-JAR solution and instead produced a separate -sources.jar file in Netbeans for each library by modifying the corresponding ANT build.xml.

```
  <target description="bundle sources in a jar" name="-post-jar">
    <jar basedir="${src.dir}" compress="${jar.compress}" destfile="${dist.dir}/${application.title}-sources.jar"/>
  </target>
```

Somehow the Android Studio build system auto-magically picks up on the existence of these files - so now I have source code available for debugging!